# Pre sign-up triggers in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In AWS Cognito is possible to trigger a Lambda Function pre-registration of the user.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html

I am wondering if it is possible the same in Azure. This is, trigger an Azure Function before the user is registered in AD B2C. And fail the registration if the response of the function is not 2xx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with both out-of-the-box user flows and custom policies.

For user flows you can leverage api connectors with the [before creating the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-user-flow#before-creating-the-user) trigger.

In custom policies you would need to implement your own [REST API technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) and use it the sign-up's [validation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile)